# How can I get the number of days between 2 dates in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to find an integer number of days between two dates in Oracle 11g.

I can get close by doing

```
select sysdate - to_date('2009-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
```

but this returns an interval, and I haven't been successful casting this to an integer.

Edit: Apparently in 10g, this returns the number of days as an integer.

Comment: that SQL should return a numeric value, not an interval

Comment: Only 10+ years later - [here's a db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=22fb6f998fa99e722472e5bbb7b3bfb5) which demonstrates the difference between subtracting a date from a date (e.g. SYSDATE) and subtracting a date from a timestamp (e.g. SYSTIMESTAMP). The former produces a number representing the count of days between the two dates, while the latter produces an interval representation of the days between the two dates. Actually, introducing a TIMESTAMP anywhere in the calculation results in an INTERVAL being returned, so perhaps OP had redefined SYSDATE.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I figured it out myself.  I need

```
select extract(day from sysdate - to_date('2009-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')) from dual
```

Comment: Weird.  As with the other answerers, when I do your original query, I get a number, not an interval.  And when I try your solution, I get an error, ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source.  This is in Oracle 10g; what version are you using?

Comment: 11g. That could be it.  Thanks Dave.

Comment: Using systimestamp instead of sysdate means that it does timestamp rather than date arithmetic, which gives INTERVALs as a result. But I can't reproduce your experience with sysdate.

Comment: select extract(day from sysdate - cast(date '2009-10-01' as timestamp)) from dual

Comment: I think @Tony Andrews answers the question better.

Answer (score 59):

Or you could have done this:

```
select trunc(sysdate) - to_date('2009-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
```

This returns a NUMBER of whole days:

```
SQL> create view v as 
  2  select trunc(sysdate) - to_date('2009-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') diff 
  3  from dual;

View created.

SQL> select * from v;

      DIFF
----------
        29

SQL> desc v
 Name                   Null?    Type
 ---------------------- -------- ------------------------
 DIFF                            NUMBER(38)
```

Comment: This still returns an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

Comment: No it doesn't, what makes you say that?

Comment: Proof that it returns a NUMBER and not an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND added to answer.

Comment: Not relevant now, but for completeness' sake. 10g was returning a NUMBER, and 11g was returning an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND.

Comment: @BrianRamsay It's odd that you had that experience, but I can assure you that 11g returned a NUMBER also - as does 19c which I use today.  If the behaviour had changed beween 10g and 11g, an awful lot of code would have been broken and Oracle would have had to issue a fix PDQ!  You can confirm 11g behaviour on sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 6):

You can try using:

```
select trunc(sysdate - to_date('2009-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')) as days from dual
```

Comment: trunc() did not work for me.  I got this error: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER, got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

Comment: oh yeah .. cause u dont have the HH24:MI:SS part in the second date .. glad u got it figured out urself

Answer (score 1):

This will work i have tested myself.
It gives difference between sysdate and date fetched from column admitdate

```
  TABLE SCHEMA:
    CREATE TABLE "ADMIN"."DUESTESTING" 
    (   
  "TOTAL" NUMBER(*,0), 
"DUES" NUMBER(*,0), 
"ADMITDATE" TIMESTAMP (6), 
"DISCHARGEDATE" TIMESTAMP (6)
    )

EXAMPLE:
select TO_NUMBER(trunc(sysdate) - to_date(to_char(admitdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd')) from admin.duestesting where total=300
```

Answer (score 1):

- Full days between end of month and start of today, including the last day of the month:

  ```
  SELECT LAST_DAY (TRUNC(SysDate)) - TRUNC(SysDate) + 1 FROM dual
  ```
- Days between using exact time:

  ```
  SELECT SysDate - TO_DATE('2018-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') FROM dual
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below query for your answer. I am choosing a dummy date in the second part. You can replace it with any date per your requirements.

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SysDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')  - TO_DATE('2018-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') FROM dual
```