# Sql Trunc Math issue

Tags: sql, oracle

When I using

```
select trunc(sysdate) from dual
```

I got the correct date which is today in a good format. like "6/24/2013"

And if I do

```
select trunc(sysdate)-1 from dual
```

I got yesterday date with a good format.

However, if i do:

```
select trunc(sysdate)- trunc(sysdate-1) from dual
```

I suppose to get 1, but what i got is **/d/yyyy**

All I want to do is calculate how many days between two dates. By using **Trunc(date) - Trunc(another date),** I always got **/d/yyyy** rather than the days between this two dates.

How can do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646001/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-2-dates-in-oracle-11g

Comment: If I run the SQL statement you indicate you're running in SQL*Plus, I get a result of `1`.  Can you edit your post to include a cut and paste from a SQL*Plus session that shows exactly what you are running and exactly what result you get.

Comment: Your query should work and return 1, can you post actual date values you are using. [Working demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12699)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a days_between function: DAYS_BETWEEN(date1, date2), so your query could be expressed as:

```
select abs(days_between(trunc(sysdate),trunc(sysdate-1))) from dual
```

I have included the abs() function as I can't remember off hand whether the most recent date should go first or second to get a positive result and don't have access to check right now.

Comment: I got unknow function dats_between

Comment: No it doesn't... except [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A60725_05/html/comnls/us/per/ffugax15.htm). The RDBMS doesn't have, or need, that function.

Comment: I have used this and Months_Between in Oracle before. Here is a link with further details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A60725_05/html/comnls/us/per/ffugax15.htm

Comment: That's what I linked to, it isn't core SQL. [`months_between` is though](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions102.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Just use minus (-) Oracle stores dates as numbers and 1 = 1day

so sysdate + 1 is tomorrow, sysdate - 1 is yesterday

From SQL fiddle
TRUNC(SYSDATE)-TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)
1

Comment: That's what the OP says he's doing?

Comment: And if you try it it works ok?. Is there any chance of getting a failing example on SQL Fiddle?