# ORA-30076 when trying to find days between dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying to find the no of days between 2 dates.
I tried running the below query and ended up with **ORA-30076** error.

Query is,

```
select extract(day from (sysdate - to_date('2009-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))) 
 from dual
```

Error is,

```
Error at Command Line:1 Column:34
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source
30076. 00000 -  "invalid extract field for extract source"
*Cause:    The extract source does not contain the specified extract field.
```

But when i try to run

```
Select extract(day from sysdate) from dual;
```

i got correct output.

Please help if anyone knows the reason as why i am getting the above error.

Comment: You don't need extract, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646001/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-2-dates-in-oracle-11g

Comment: Use simply `date'2009-10-01'` instead of to_date.

Comment: `sysdate - to_date('2009-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` is enough. No need for `extract`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subtracting one date from another doesn't return a date, it returns a number that represents the number of days difference so you can't use extract.

Answer (score 3):

`sysdate - to_date('2009-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` will give the difference **in days** between two dates - there is no need to use `extract` function. Moreover in this situation it would be incorrect usage of `extract` function simply because it would expect expression of date or interval datatype after `from` clause and result of `sysdate - to_date('2009-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` subtraction is of number datatype - cause of the error you are facing.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
 sysdate - to_date('2009-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

returns a number, not a date.  You can only extract days from dates.