# IS Equation in oracle to get date in month?

Tags: oracle

I try to get the difference between 20201001-20200930 is 71 not 1 day
try to get difference between sysdate(20201127) and 20200106 is 1021
10 refer to number of months and 21 refer to the number of days

```
select GetDate(sysdate)-floor(D.INIT_TIMESTAMP) FROM T_NOTIFICATION
```

I try to get the difference between 20201001-20200930 is 71 not 1 day

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the number of days between 2 dates in Oracle 11g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646001/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-2-dates-in-oracle-11g)

Comment: What is the type of input data you have? There's no `getdate` function in Oracle. Moreover, I do not know any DBMS that can have some input parameter for `getdate` or its analog.

Answer (score 0):

Juste convert into DATE datatype before computing the difference.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('20201001', 'YYYYMMDD') - TO_DATE('20200930', 'YYYYMMDD') 
FROM dual;
```

EDIT :
IYYY  changed into YYYY according Oracle docs -> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

Comment: Format `IYYY` is the 4-digit year of the year containing the calendar week, as defined by the ISO 8601 standard. It can be used only for output, i.e. `TO_CHAR()`

Comment: use YYYYMMDD instead

Answer (score 0):

There is no `GetDate` function in Oracle. Try this one:

```
TRUNC(sysdate) - TO_DATE(20200106, 'YYYYMMDD')
TO_DATE(20201001, 'YYYYMMDD') - TO_DATE(20200930, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Comment: GETDATE is function I make it to transform date into number