# Oracle Database | Calculate Days in between two dates

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to calculate number of days in between to DATES stored in my database, but I was not able to get any data using DATEDIFF or Extract.

Brief Example:

TABLE (PROJECT)
PROJECT START, PROJECT END

What I'm looking to get is the amount of days each project lasted.

Any hint will help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646001/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-2-dates-in-oracle-11g

Answer (score 0):

When you subtract one date from another in Oracle, you get a decimal value. The numbers to the left of the decimal point are the days, the numbers to the right is the decimal fraction.

```
  select sysdate - date '2022-01-03' as delta from dual;
```

The resulting value on the day I am running this is 37.65. Since you asked for days, I'll leave it to you to truncate this to 37 days or round it to 38.